# how I can print the values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

hello every one I'm trying to check a key in a dictionary and print it's value as output. but it pass
the item and nothing won't happen.

I write this code:

```
dict1={
    "apple":130,
    "avocado":50,
    "banana":110,
    "cantaloupe":50,
    "grapefruit":60,
    "grapes":90,
    "honeydew melon":50,
    "kiwifruit":90,
    "lemon":15,
    "lime":20,
    "nectarine":60,
    "orange":80,
    "peach":60,
    "pear":100,
    "pineapple":50,
    "plums":50,
    "sweet Cherries":100,
    "tangerine":50,
    "watermelon":80
}
a=input("item: ")
a=a.casefold()
for key in dict1:
    if key==a :
        print:("calories: ",str(dict1[key]))
```

I expect if input is apple...the output be 130 but i get ""

Comment: You have a typo. Remove the colon after the `print` keyword: `print("calories: ",str(dict1[key]))`

Comment: @lemon colon, not semicolon

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the colon was doing.  My first thought was a named goto label, but Python doesn't have those.  My next thought was a key:value dictionary item, but it isn't inside curly braces.  Was it being treated as a type hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all.

```py
a=input("item: ").casefold()
print(dict1[a])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a dict key, just use:

```
>>print(dict['key'])
>>'value'
```

For your case

```py
print(dict1['apple'])
```

Should give 130 as output

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be using the .get method on dict if the key is found it returns the corresponding value if not it returns a default value.
For your example replace the code :

```
for key in dict1:
if key==a :
    print:("calories: ",str(dict1[key]))
```

With the following code :

```
print:("calories: ",str(dict1.get(key, 'default-value-of-yourchoice')))
```